# Wie vergleichbar sind die Widerstände gegen die Rechtschreibreformen 1876 und 1901 mit denen von 1996?

Tags: history, reformed-orthography

Gab es 1876 und 1901 auch derartige Widerstände wie gegen die Rechtschreibreform von 1996 und ihre Folgereformen? Was wurde damals anders oder evtl. besser gemacht?

Answer (score 4):

Ich zitiere aus http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rechtschreibreform

----- Beginn Zitat -----
Im deutschen Sprachraum fanden zwei orthografische Konferenzen statt, auf denen neben dem Ziel einer Vereinheitlichung der deutschen Orthografie auch weitergehende Reformvorschläge diskutiert wurden. In erster Linie führten sie zu der angestrebten Vereinheitlichung der Rechtschreibung. Die erste Reform scheiterte; ihre Ideen wurden weitgehend in der zweiten Reform umgesetzt:

- _4. bis 15. Januar 1876: „Konferenz zur Herstellung größerer Einigung auf dem Gebiet der deutschen Orthographie“ (I. Orthographische Konferenz) in Berlin;
- _17. bis 19. Juni 1901: „Beratungen über die Einheitlichkeit der deutschen Rechtschreibung“ (II. Orthographische Konferenz) in Berlin.

Beide Konferenzen standen im Licht der Öffentlichkeit und wurden insbesondere von den überregionalen Tageszeitungen wie der Kölnischen Zeitung heftig diskutiert:

> „Wir haben gesehen, dass die Vocale a o u und ihre Umlaute von der Verdoppelung und dem Parasiten h befreit werden sollen. In dieser Aufzählung vermissen wir leider e und i. Diese armen Lettern werden wegen ihrer Dünnleibigkeit verdammt, den falschen Hauchlaut als ewige Last mit sich herumzuschleppen; nehmen, stehlen, kehren und ähnliche Wörter bleiben in jenem Stallwinkel liegen, wohin die reinigenden Fluten des Alpheios nicht dringen sollen.“

– Kölnische Zeitung: 27. Januar 1876

----- Ende Zitat -----

Es gab also auch damals Widerstände, was auch aus der Tatsche abgeleitet werden kann, dass die Reform von 1876 nicht angenommen wurde und als gescheitert gilt. Erst im zweiten Anlauf (1901) gelang mit dem Druck "der Obrigkeit" die gewünschte Vereinheitlichung der deutschen Sprache.

Übrigens zeigt das "dass" (mit Doppel-s) im zitierten Zeitungsausschnitt (korrekt nach der Rechtschreibung vor 1876), dass sich die deutsche Sprache nicht in eine bestimmte Richtung bewegt.

Comment: Interessant daran ist insbesondere, dass die Reform zumindest der Kölnischen Zeitung anscheinend nicht weit genug ging, wohingegen in neuerer Zeit die Zeitungen lieber die alte Rechtschreibung behalten wollten. (Was ja auch in vielen "kann, muss aber nicht"-Regeln resultiert ist.)

Answer (score 2):

Man seems to be a creature of habit. I suppose this was the case already in those days.

> 1876   Die erste Orthographiekonferenz zur "Herstellung größerer Einigung in der deutschen Rechtschreibung" endet ergebnislos.
>   1869    Eine orthographische Konferenz in Österreich erarbeitet Grundsätze, die im Österreichischen Schulboten veröffentlicht werden, sich aber nicht durchsetzen.
>   [...]
>   1901    Die "II. orthographische Konferenz", in der vor allem Behörden vertreten sind, beschließt die "Regeln für die deutsche Rechtschreibung nebst Wörterverzeichnis", die durch den "Duden" allgemeine Anerkennung finden. Die beschlossenen Regeln sind weniger radikal als die von 1876, u. a. wird die Heysesche ss-Schreibung abgelehnt und daraufhin 1902 in Österreich wiederabgeschafft.
>   [...]
>   <sub>http://www.schriftdeutsch.de/orth-his.htm</sub>

Possibly due to the higher degree of circulation of mass media and means for written communication things become on the one hand side more easy to propagate but at the same time more hard to establish.

Answer (score -1):

Es gab einen berühmten Einspruch: Kaiser Wilhelm hat sich persönlich dafür eingesetzt, dass der Thron sein "h" behielt.